# Bootstrap checkbox buttons not changing state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I used to have radio buttons, but I changed the script to use bootstrap checkboxes. But it is not changing the state when using bootstrap switches.

This is snippet of my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio-list">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="upd_active" class="updactive" id="upd_yes" value="1" checked> Yes </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="upd_active" class="updactive" id="upd_no" value="0"> No </label>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function action(){}
        var parentflag = $('#upd_yes').parents('.form-group');
        parentflag.find('span').removeClass('checked');
        if(is_active == "1"){
            $("#upd_no").attr('checked', false);
            $("#upd_yes").attr('checked', true);
            $('#upd_yes').parent().addClass('checked');
        }
        else{
            $("#upd_yes").attr('checked', false);
            $("#upd_no").attr('checked', true);
            $('#upd_no').parent().addClass('checked');
        }
    }
    </script>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">IsActive<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-md-8">
         <input type="checkbox" name="upd_active" class="make-switch updactive" id="upd_yes" value="1" checked>
     </div>
</div>

<script>
    function action(){
        var parentflag = $('#upd_yes').parents('.form-group');
        parentflag.find('span').removeClass('checked');
        if(is_active == "1"){
            $("#upd_yes").attr("checked",true);
            $('#upd_yes').parent().addClass('checked');
        }
        else{
            $("#upd_yes").attr("checked",false);
            $('#upd_yes').parent().removeClass('checked');
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is `is_active` initialized?

Comment: lets say is_active is declared to be 1

Comment: Guys please dont search for syntax errors !!! all are declared properly and working fine, but when we are including bootstrap it is not showing the actions...Pls help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Am able to find 2 issues(actually not issues) as below

1. `is_active` is not declared so you cannot check it with if statement
2. Most importantly your `action()` function not at all initiated.

So i added below code and updated the snippet.

```
var is_active = 0;
action();
```

```js
var is_active = 0;
action();

function action() {
  var parentflag = $('#upd_yes').parents('.form-group');
  parentflag.find('span').removeClass('checked');
  if (is_active == "1") {
    $("#upd_yes").attr("checked", true);
    $('#upd_yes').parent().addClass('checked');
  } else {
    $("#upd_yes").attr("checked", false);
    $('#upd_yes').parent().removeClass('checked');
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">IsActive<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="checkbox" name="upd_active" class="make-switch updactive" id="upd_yes" value="1" checked>
  </div>
</div>
```